# Scrolling horizontally between multiple images using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

If we start with the photos app for example. The images can be viewed with a swipe and the images scroll into view as the user swipes.

How is this kind of UIScrollView setup and how are the Images (e.g. from an array) displayed within this UISCrollView?

Are the images added to the scrollview at once or how is this paging look achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved using a main `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES` and containing nested `UIScrollViews`. Then you can put an `UIImageView` in each one of these nested scroll views, so you can also achieve zooming by returning it to `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:`

Also, you can take a look at these samples from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: So I create a UIScrollView for each Image I have. What about UIImageViews for these?

Comment: Thanks. So I got it working, but how do I set the scrollview to display  certain image once the images have all be added to the scrollview. E.g. clicking a thumbnail, set the scrollview in another class to display the image with the correct index.

Comment: @Helium3: you can use `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated`. The content offset calculation would look like: `float contentOffset = desiredIndex * scrollView.frame.size.width;` Also, please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: i did the same thing but the app started giving memory warning after loading a no of photos to the scroller. Reason may be the size of the images. Please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: ScrollViews.pagingEnabled = YES; .. save my time dude :)