# Slide animation for UITabBar controller, horizontally in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Currently I am using UITabbar Controller to show my application's views. I would like slide to slide it horizontally away on certain view changes. Can I slide UITabbar controller ? or any other options?

This is my UITabbar controller.

[image: UITAbbar controller]

I want to slide it horizontally or I want any other tool bar that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer following link, it may be helpful to you.

[Horizontal UIScrollView and hundreds of thumbnail images in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973883/horizontal-uiscrollview-and-hundreds-of-thumbnail-images-in-ios)

[iOS - Horizontally sliding items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777450/ios-horizontally-sliding-items)

[Scrolling horizontally between multiple images using UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085239/scrolling-horizontally-between-multiple-images-using-uiscrollview)

Comment: Thankz for the answer.I can implement own one using this examples. :)